# ReactJS from hash from BrowserRouter

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using BrowserRouter like this:

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={HomePage} />
        <Redirect exact path="/" to="/" />
    </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

When I run my app the URL looks like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/#/
```

But I want it to look like this:

```
http://localhost:8080
```

No hash at all and 1 or none slashes. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that work for me :

```
   import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom'


     <Router>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/"  render={({ location }) => (
                    <Redirect to={location.hash.replace('#', '')} />
                  )} component={HomePage} />
                <Redirect exact path="/" to="/" />
            </Switch>
    </Router>
```

Only routes that have `/#` will match `/`.

One could easily add a conditional if needed to render something on root.